# Элемент чата на js

Tags: php, javascript

На данный момент делаю переписку между пользователями на js и php. Как вывести сообщение пользователю о том, что он получил новое письмо без перезагрузки?

Comment: ajax, comet.

Comment: Вы можете привести пример использования comet?

Comment: Вы можете сами найти множество примеров в сети. Например: http://spectrox.ru/blog/comet-theory-beginning/

Comment: [Вебсокеты][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: пока еще нестандарт, поэтому пусть подождут..

Comment: @deivan уважаемый, вы смеетесь чтоль?
Google Chrome (начиная с версии 4.0.249.0);
Apple Safari (начиная с версии 5.0.7533.16);
Mozilla Firefox (начиная с версии 4);
Opera (начиная с версии 10.70 9067);
Internet Explorer (начиная с версии 10 PP5);

Answer (score 3):

Отправить Ajax запрос на сервер типа "получить данные личных сообщений", как бы опросить таблицу на наличие новых записей.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/newmess",
    data: {
        newmes: get,
        uid = 123123
    } // uid - ID пользователя
}).done(function (html) {
    var res = JSON.parse(html);
    if (res.status == 1) alert('Есть новые сообщения');
    else alert('Сообщений нет');
})
```

Ну а в файле по адресу **/ajax/newmess**

```
if (isset($_POST['newmes'])) {
    mysql_query(SELECT bla-bla from tablename where uid='.$_POST['uid'].');
    if (есть новое то) {
        $options = array(
            'status' => 1,
            'error' => 'есть сообщение'
        );
        echo json_encode($options);
    } else {
        $options = array(
            'status' => 0,
            'error' => 'нет сообщений'
        );
        echo json_encode($options);            
    }
}
```

В двух словах так, но учитывать проверки и прочее.

Comment: А как запускать ajax запрос? т.е. мне нужно отправлять каждые n милисекунд ajax запрос?

Comment: Обворачиваете ajax запрос в функцию. Вызываете рекурсивно.

Comment: Jquery в помощь, писать весь код за тебя никто не будет, просил помочь, помогаем, но писать полностью не будем.

как написал @lampa обернуть в функцию и по N секунд отправлять запрос.

Comment: *как написал @lampa обернуть в функцию и по N секунд отправлять запрос*

а как быть если людей 100500? Вы представляете нагрузку?

Comment: Собственно что в этом такого? Какова задача, такова и нагрузка. Как раз можно спокойно запилить сервер, держащий эти 100500 соединений. Всё дело, что будет использоваться: БД для синхронизации, хранение в памяти или что-то еще.

Comment: > а как быть если людей 100500? Вы представляете нагрузку?

Когда людей станет 100500, можно отдельный сервер запилить под это дело.